# flashcards by using google spreadsheet

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

I am trying to create `flashcards` by using `google spreadsheet`.

I tried the way suggested at this [page](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/make-flashcards-google-docs-spreadsheets-web-iosandroid/)

It produces a panel containing the flashcards but actually it is empty.

I am using the last version of google chrome to produce it.

To me, the `flashcards gadget`, embedded into google dive, seems too old to work with the current version of google chrome.

My questions are:

1. Could it be possible?
2. What could be an alternative way to make flashcards related to your gmail account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According `Google Drive Support`  the `Gadgets in Google Spreadsheets` will be deprecated.
http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=15165&answer=2791335.

A good alternative could be `http://api.flashcardstogo.com/webapp/`

Answer (score 1):

Since gadgets have now been deprecated the makeuseof method no longer works.

Fortunately http://flippity.net/ provides similar functionality using publicly shared (obfuscated) links.

**Tip:** Create a study topic bookmark folder in your bookmarks containing links to both your google spreadsheet and the flippity generated flashcard. That way you can open both with, right-click + "open all bookmarks". It makes it easier to study and add new cards.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple solution in Excel.   Place your questions in Column A, and your Answers in Column B.   Then Colorall of Column B as White Font to start your session.

To expose the answers one at at time use this code:

Sub Flash_Questions_A()

'' ANSWER COLUMN, is in Column B, format it "White" to start the session
'' Question COLUMN, is in Column A
'' Place CURSOR in cell "A1" to start the Flash Card Session

```
Dim currentCell As Range
Dim targetCell As Range
Dim NextCell As Range

Set currentCell = ActiveCell ' Assuming the current selection is the active cell
Set targetCell = currentCell.Offset(0, 1) ' Offset by 0 rows and 1 column

currentCell.Copy ' Copy formatting from current cell
targetCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats ' Paste formatting in the target cell

Application.CutCopyMode = False ' Clear the copy mode

Set NextCell = targetCell.Offset(1, -1)
NextCell.Select
```

End Sub

'you can then set a shortcut key to the code to activate it with a keystroke.